# Do when browser is closed

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I know this is stupid question, but will solve my doubts.

I am implementing a web application in `ASP.NET` `MVC 4`,in which user has to upload some document.I have a view where user has to upload file, write title,description in text boxes.I will make file upload as ajax and after its submission, user has to write titles etc.m then submit.

I want to know that this may happen that user will upload file using ajax only and then close the window.This way the file has been upload ,but has no use.

So, I want to ask that can it be possible that in such cases , file is deleted from the server as well or there can be other similar solution?
Thanks ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's better to insert a record on database at upload times, which indicates which files are useful and which have to be deleted, then you can write a service that execute for example every one hour to delete useless files.